# Microsoft word alignment in paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

I'm having some trouble with my paragraph alignment here on microsoft word

I have this
[image]

I want this

[image]

I want to align all the lines on the right side of the margin, just like in the picture. In mine there are several irregularities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda hard to figure out what you want us to help you with, but I assume you want to *justify* your text, or make the right side flush to the margin.

Select the part of the text then do Ctrl Shift J to justify.

or click the icon in here: [image]

If you want the spacing before the paragraph as well, that's called an *indent* and you do that by pressing the tab key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to justify your text, then indent the first line of each paragraph.

Select all of your text using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Now press the Justify icon [image: justify icon] under the Home tab.

Then on the first line of the paragraph, use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent the text.

You can use Paragraph Settings to set this as the document's default.

[image: Paragraph settings]